# How can I find the length of a given GArray?

Tags: c, glib

I have a GArray of GValue (all non-zero) which has been allocated at runtime with g_array_append_val. I wonder how can I find out what's the index of the last element, or more precisely how many elements does the array hold. Code like

```
for (length=0;g_value_get_int(&g_array_index(array, GValue, length)); length++);
return length
```

would fail with an out of bounds.

Comment: It is up to you to keep track of the number of elements you have added to the garray. When created, a garray allocates a block of memory sufficient to hold a significant number of elements without reallocation and has a refcount of `1`. (this is done specifically to prevent frequent reallocation) I don't know of any way to tell exactly how many elements can be added before reallocation without looking at the glib source. See [**glib - Arrays**](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Seems unlikely. How would `g_array_append_val` work if GArrays don't keep track of their size?

Comment: Point well taken, that is why I referred the OP to the source, because it wasn't documented in the glib - Arrays documentation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be well-documented, but the number of the elements in the array is stored in the field `array->len`.

It's described [here](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.Array.html).

Comment: Thanks! Ohh man I should've looked at the source file at least! is right there in the first struct _GArray, the doxygen in the source file says
/**
 * GArray:
 * data: a pointer to the element data. The data may be moved as
 *     elements are added to the #GArray.
 * len: the number of elements in the #GArray not including the
 *     possible terminating zero element.
 *
 * Contains the public fields of a GArray.
 */

Comment: For future reference, it's documented [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html#GArray).